# Trying to read csv using python to pythonanywhere host

Tags: python, django, csv, encoding, utf-8

We are trying to read a csv file using view.py in pythonanywhere.com host.
We want to get three cells (id, statement, and paragraph) from each row in the 1.csv file until last one.

The code is:

```
def home(request):

    Stats = Statments.objects.all()

    __file__ = '1.csv'

    module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # get current directory
    file_name = os.path.join(module_dir, 'Politi_Stat/1.csv')

    #Load statments to database from CSV
    with open(file_name,"r", encoding = 'utf-8') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            book = Statments(id = row[0] ,statment=row[1], Paragraph=row[2])
            book.save()


    d = deque(posts)
    d.extendleft(reversed(Stats))
```

We import the csv and os. It seems an encoding problem of the unicode UTF-8 of csv.

The output of the site is:
Server 500

The output from the log file is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fattoh/.virtualenvs/django2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fattoh/.virtualenvs/django2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/fattoh/.virtualenvs/django2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/fattoh/Politi_Stat/app/views.py", line 46, in home
    for row in csv_reader:
  File "/home/fattoh/.virtualenvs/django2/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 82: invalid start byte
2019-11-27 19:20:54,714: Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fattoh/.virtualenvs/django2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fattoh/.virtualenvs/django2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/fattoh/.virtualenvs/django2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/fattoh/Politi_Stat/app/views.py", line 46, in home
    for row in csv_reader:
  File "/home/fattoh/.virtualenvs/django2/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
```

Comment: The csv file isn't UTF-8 encoded.  Was it created on a Windows machine?

Comment: created on a Mac OS. but I am using windows now.

Comment: if the csv file isn't utf-8 encoded then your code won't work

Comment: Okay, thanks for this notification.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your csv is not utf8 encoded. You are specifying utf8 as the encoding when you load it. Specify the correct encoding for the file when you load it and it will work.